# Add two values from an array to give total

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The main purpose of this application is i need an overall score once the user selects multiple selections all the functionality is working however once i click the generate overall score button i want to see the overall score. But i can't i just see the whole array with each individual value.

```js
const scoreValue1 = `The Score Is: ${ theScores.scores0}`;

const appendedValue = $("#score-1").append(scoreValue1);
console.log(appendedValue);

totalScores.push(scoreValue1)

const scoreValue2C = `The Score Is: ${ theScores.scores2}`;
const appendedValue = $("#score-2").append(scoreValue2C);
console.log(appendedValue);

totalScores.push(scoreValue2C)

const totalScores = []
```

Screenshots: 
[Overall Score Result Total Score Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPPbG.png)
[Appended Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhJzB.png)
[Appended Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmsHP.png)

Comment: If you're unclear why your [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457158/2-functions-that-push-values-into-an-array-but-i-want-to-keep-an-overall-score-b) was closed, please add a comment.  There's no point just asking the exact same question.

Comment: So loop over the array and add the values together.

Answer (score -1):

If i correctly understood, you have an array which contains integers.
And you want to sum all of these numbers ?

If yes, you can use ".reduce()" function.

```
//Imagine, your result array is like this
const totalScore = [1, 2, 3]

const sum = totalScore.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return acc + val;
}, 0);

console.log(sum); // output is 6
```

Comment: Thanks how would i return in a templated format?

Comment: If i wanted to inject it into a div

Comment: If your div looks like this :
```<div id="totalScore"></div>```

You can replace the console.log(sum); with :

```document.querySelector('#totalScore').innerHTML = sum```

Comment: index.js:623 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Comment: Ohh no, just put ```document.querySelector("#totalScore").innerHTML = sum```, forget about the console.log :) if you're having trouble, show me your html where you want to display the total score.

Comment: I done it a different way

Comment: Nice, don't forget to mark as resolved, good luck for your application :)

Comment: Sorry dude if im asking too many questions what if i wanted to add both the values and divide by two i know the assignment opperator is %2 but where do i place it

Comment: You can do like that :
```document.querySelector('#totalScore').innerHTML = sum%2```

Comment: const theOverallScore= totalScores.reduce((acc,val)=>{
        return acc  + val  ;
      },0)


      const overallValues = `<div id="totalScore">${theOverallScore%2}</div>`

Comment: This is what i did but the %2 dose'nt seem to work

Comment: Ohhh forget, after the reduce, put "/2", just like that :
```const theOverallScore= totalScores.reduce((acc,val)=>{ return acc + val ; },0)/2;```

Comment: It's not returning the value halfed

Comment: const theOverallScore= totalScores.reduce((acc,val)=>{
        return acc  + val  ;
      },0%2)

Comment: You asked me for "divide by two", so the correct operator would be ```/2``` instead of ```"%2"```, try both and it should work

Comment: Without the code under my eyes, i can't be precise, push on github or liveshare vscode

Comment: Put the ```/2``` after the parenthesis, not before ^^

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the console for any error? The keyword 'const' in JavaScript works a little bit differently than let and var. Any variables declared with var will be hoisted. This means that you can access the variable without the JavaScript engine throws an error. However, the value of that variable will be undefined.
Any variables declared with the let keyword are not hoisted. This means that when you try to access the variable created with var, it will throw an error.
Const works the same way but you cannot change the value. In this case, you are trying to push an array element without declaring a first. Therefore, the JavaScript engine will throw a reference error. A good practice is always declare your variable with let or const first. This will not only prevent the polution of the global object )window for browser, global for nodejs), but it also reduces the amount of errors. Since you did not provide enough debugging details, there is nothing I can do for you.